# metal shader language random numbers

Tags: shader, metal

In metal shader language , using metals standard library for functions
is pretty straightforward eg, a step within a fragment function can be called:

```
float borderRed = step(150, position.x);
```

What Im trying to find is any kind of metal function that return a random number
(preferably between 0.0 and 1.0) which is along the same usage lines as fract floor e.t.c

anyone know of one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ported the pseudo-random [Gold Noise](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ltB3zD) to Metal. It will produce "random" values per frame provided you pass it a unique number each pass for the seed parameter.

For instance, you can pass your shader a frame counter, a time stamp or one random number to use for the seed.

If you want the same initial "random" values, just use the same seed.

```
// Gold Noise ©2015 dcerisano@standard3d.com
//  - based on the Golden Ratio, PI and Square Root of Two
//  - superior distribution
//  - fastest noise generator function

constant float PHI = 1.61803398874989484820459 * 00000.1; // Golden Ratio
constant float PI_factor  = 3.14159265358979323846264 * 00000.1; // PI
constant float SQ2 = 1.41421356237309504880169 * 10000.0; // Square Root of Two

//Note: I added `* 00000.1` and `* 10000.0` because IIRC I was getting overflows.

float goldNoise(float2 coordinate, float seed) {
    return fract(tan(distance(coordinate * (seed + PHI), float2(PHI, PI_factor))) * SQ2);
}
```

I use this too, with xy from the shader and a different seed per pass:

```
float rand0to1(int x, int y, int passSeed)
{
    int seed = x + y * 57 + passSeed * 241;
    seed = (seed<< 13) ^ seed;
    return (( 1.f - ( (seed * (seed * seed * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 2147483647) / 1073741824.0f) + 1.0f) / 2.0f;
}
```

Comment: those make good patterns, I notice Mr Cerisano copyrighted the g.n function - so Im not going to use that even tho its good + quick lol, the second one, is that yours?

Comment: I think he just wants his copyright distributed with any source code. If you look at other Shadertoys, people explicitly state when they are not allowed for commercial use etc. The second one is from Apple's sample code (with a permissive license): https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/MetalShaderShowcase/Listings/MetalShaderShowcase_AAPLWoodShader_metal.html